# Problem updating and installing

Tags: updates, wine

I am new to Ubuntu , having just decided to move from windows and a having some problems .

I cannot seem to install anything from the software manager , it wont even start downloading and when it does it gets halfway and stops .

I am trying to install wine and have tried through terminal . I tried to update first using sudo apt-get update but get alot of 404 errors and then it hangs . I then try 
sudo apt-get install wine1.6 and it starts but also many 404 issues then stops .

I am running ubuntu mint . version 14.something . Please can someone try help this non ubuntu user to fix my problems . Thank you

Comment: Your software manager and `apt-get` try to connect to one of the Ubuntu mirror servers to retrieve packages. Apparently, the connection to the server is dodgy. It would be useful to know if you are using the correct server for your region. Either your internet connection itself is unreliable, or you are using an unreliable mirror. Please edit your question and add the full 404 error message (one will do).

Answer (score 0):

My advice to you would be to make absolutely certain your installation is fully updated.  As I am not a mint user, I'm not sure how to advise you, but if it is anything like Ubuntu, it should be as easy as pressing the windows key on your keyboard, typing UPDATE, pressing enter, and then pressing on the CHECK button, prior to pressing on the UPDATE button.

May I ask why you chose MINT over Ubuntu?

Comment: Thanks guys , For some reason I thought that was ubuntu . Have now intalled ubuntu 12 which I updated to 14 and everything seems to working fine now . Am really enjoying ubuntu so far :)

Comment: I understand the ubuntu/mint confusion for the reason that a lot of serious ubuntu users jumped ship when Ubuntu began using Unity instead of learning the significant advantages of an interface built on efficiency as opposed to emulating WINDOWS as I perceive the gnome interface to do.  Nevertheless, people went elsewhere, many choosing to use either MINT or Lubuntu (Light Ubuntu) which features the gnome interface.  If I have an issue with unity, it would be that I have yet to find a comprehensive guide to its use.   This is why I wrote a guide to it which, I did post... somewhere.